# Turn off form autosaving on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a form for composing an email, we autosave changes, using a timer. This works fine. But there appears to be a race when the form is submitted, especially with IE11. On submit, we want to turn off the autosaving before the submit happens. We have instances in production where we'll get simultaneous calls to the server to save a draft as well as to submit the form.

```
var timeoutId;
var deleted = false;

// setup a call to onFormChange when a change happens
$('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    onFormChange();
});

function onFormChange() {
  // call saveDraft 1 second after changes happen
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {saveDraft();}, 1000);
}

// saveDraft saves the current form state in the draft.
function saveDraft() {
  if (deleted == true) {
    // don't save because we're done
    return;
  }
  var fromval = $("#from").val();
  var subject = $("#subject").val();
  var body = $("#body").val();

  //
  // upload is done here using $.post()
  //
}

$('form').submit(function(e){
  // stop saving drafts when we do a submit
  deleted = true;
  if( $(this).hasClass('form-submitted') ){
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  $(this).addClass('form-submitted');
});
```

Comment: It looks like you disable the auto-save with `clearTimeout(timeoutId);`, or am I mistaken?  Where in your submit handler do you try to disable the auto-save?

Comment: Pending XHR requests are probably going through after submission. Try setting your `$.post` to a global variable, and then calling `myVar.abort()` in the same place as `deleted = true` to cancel any pending draft save requests.

Comment: @David the `deleted` var handles this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the timer when you submit the form.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  // stop saving drafts when we do a submit
  deleted = true;
  if( $(this).hasClass('form-submitted') ){
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  $(this).addClass('form-submitted');
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Comment: Ah, missed that. +1 for noticing the timer. So the optimum solution then would be to clear the timeout as well as cancelling any pending XHR.